# How do I create a new View (or subView) with the tap of a button in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I am currently making a flashcard app, and I am trying to make a button that creates an entirely new View (or subView) for the user to edit. Should I use Container Views? Collection Views? I also want to have these set to only one View Controller, so I can save the "cards" in one "set". Please Help!!

Edit: How can I save these views in a "folder" so the user can look at them later. Is there an efficient way to do this so the app doesn't slow or stop.

Edit #2: Ok, so I'm kind of getting it... collection views. But how would I implement this into my because I am using tvOS. Any thoughts?

Comment: Collection View would probably be easiest - you can make each cell the size of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a new `UIView` programmatically, it's actually quite simple. You could create a method like this:

```
func addNewView(to container: UIView) {

    let newView = UIView()
    container.addSubview(newView)
    newView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    newView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 200, height: 250)

}
```

That would create a new view inside whichever container view you passed in with a blue background, 10pts from the left (x-axis), 50pts from the top (y-axis, think a normal cartesian coordinate system with the y-axis inverted), width of 200 and height of 250.

You could then call this method on the push of a button by handling a button tap with it's own method like this:

```
func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    addNewView(to: self.view)

}
```

Obviously all the values for the frame I gave you were just for an example so you could visualize it in your head, you can edit those however you want, or make calculations based on the size of your device's screen. You can get the device's screen size by saying `self.view.bounds`

Comment: Keep in mind that after adding 5 or so views on top of each other, performance will become a concern.

Comment: @brandonscript - Good point. If the way your app works allows you to remove the cards from the screen when you are done you can improve performance by doing so. To remove a subview from it's superview, all you have to do is say `nameOfSubview.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: Or use a collection view 

Comment: @brandonscript - that would definitely be much more efficient. I just didn't know if that would work for his setup. When I think of flash card app I think one view at a a time. But you make a good point above when you say you can make one cell the size of the screen. That's probably best

Comment: Ok, so I'm kind of getting it... collection views. But how would I implement this into my because I am using tvOS. Any thoughts?